# fastlane scan returns "source is not valid JSON" error with Xcode 15.n

Tags: xcode, fastlane

I'm attempting to use `fastlane run_tests` to run our unit tests with Xcode 15.[1|2|3 Beta]. I can build the app fine for distribution, but when I run `scan` I get the following error:

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace Foo.xcworkspace -scheme Foo 2>&1
source is not valid JSON!
xcrun simctl CLI broken; run `xcrun simctl list runtimes` and make sure it works
xcrun simctl not working
```

When I run `simctl`, I get the following output:

```
== Runtimes ==
iOS 16.4 (16.4 - 20E247) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4
iOS 17.2 (17.2 - 21C62) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-2
iOS 17.4 (17.4 - 21E5195d) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-4
iOS 17.4 (17.4 - 21E5200d) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-4
```

Which clearly isn't JSON. I checked with Xcode 14.3.1 as well and I get the same behavior. The fastlane version is 2.219.0.

I'm not sure what's going on, `gym` works fine and has the same step in it.

Here is my "tests" lane that I'm executing:

```
  desc "Run unit tests"
  lane :tests do
    run_tests(workspace: "Foo.xcworkspace",
              scheme: "#{SCHEME}",
              testplan: "#{SCHEME}UnitTestPlan")
  end
```

SCHEME is set in the environment.

I get the same errors when I execute `run_tests` directly.

Any thoughts on where I should dig next?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I figured it out. It looks as though the `simctl` command has changed how it handles parameters.

Fastlane (as of 2.219.0) was calling simctl as:

```
xcrun simctl list runtimes -j
```

However, that no longer produces JSON output (`-j`).

After some experimentation, I found that the following DOES produce JSON output:

```
xcrun simctl list -j runtimes
```

So I forked Fastlane and contributed a [PR](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/21894) that fixes the behavior of the Fastlane device manager.

Hopefully, there will be a 2.220.0 soon.